# Cannot match static segment after optional segment

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'd like to have the following routing options, but I am not able to hit the last route.

- `/customers` -> empty customer component
- `/customers/:id` -> loading and rendering customer
- `/customers/:id/contacts` -> loading and rendering customer's contacts

These are my route definitions:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <SomeRoot />,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/customers/:customerId?',
                element: <Customer />,
                loader: customerLoader,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'contacts',
                        element: <CustomerContacts />,
                        loader: contactLoader
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]);
```

As `/customers` can be called with and without `:id`, I declared it optional. This works well and as expected.
However visiting `/customers/15/contacts` always renders the `<Customer />` component and I find no way around it.

I tried to declare it absolutely like `/customers/:customerId/contacts` but it again falls back to the `<Customer />` component.

As a desperate last try I used `/customers/:customerId?/contacts` but then I'll get an error saying `Absolute route path "/customers/contacts" nested under path "/customers/:customerId" is not valid. An absolute child route path must start with the combined path of all its parent routes`. So it seems to miss the optional parameter in this check completely, which makes kind of sense.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the routes configuration the path `"/customers/15/contacts"` ***should*** have been matched and both `Customer`, as a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes), and `CustomerContacts` would be rendered. If ***only*** `Customer` is rendered then I suspect it is just missing rendering an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) component for the wrapped nested routes to render their content into.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Customer = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render element here
    ...
  );
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <SomeRoot />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/customers/:customerId?',
        element: <Customer />, // <-- nested routes rendered into Outlet
        loader: customerLoader,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'contacts',
            element: <CustomerContacts />,
            loader: contactLoader
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```